# Core Data - Create a dynamic filter

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to setup a filter option for some core data records, but I'm not seeing the expected results.

Essentially, what I want is to have multiple sections. Within each section it would be an OR query, and an AND between each section. I've tried setting it up as below.

```
func getBasicFilter() -> NSPredicate? {
    var predicatesBagsLeft : [NSPredicate] = []
    var predicatesDrillType : [NSPredicate] = []
    var andPredicates : [NSPredicate] = []
    
    print("Filter List")
    print(filters)
    
    // Bags Left
    if let show = filters["showFullLeft"] {
        if show {
            print("Predicates : Show Full")
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY projectColours.fullLeft > 0")
            predicatesBagsLeft.append(predicate)
        }
    }
    if let show = filters["showPartialLeft"] {
        if show {
            print("Predicates : Show Partial")
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY projectColours.partialLeft > 0")
            predicatesBagsLeft.append(predicate)
        }
    }
    
    // Drill Types
    if let show = filters["showSquareOnly"] {
        if show {
            print("Predicates : Show Square Only")
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY projectColours.project.drillType = %@", "Square")
            predicatesDrillType.append(predicate)
        }
    }
    
    // Drill Manufacturers - TO DO

    // Combine Predicates
    
    if predicatesBagsLeft.count > 0 {
        let predicatesForBagsLeft = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .or, subpredicates: predicatesBagsLeft)
        andPredicates.append(predicatesForBagsLeft)
    }
    if predicatesDrillType.count > 0 {
        let predicatesForDrillType = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .or, subpredicates: predicatesDrillType)
        andPredicates.append(predicatesForDrillType)
    }
    
    if andPredicates.count > 0 {
        let predicates = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: andPredicates)
        
        return predicates
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

It does filter, but doesn't seem to be applying both correctly. I'm testing with a filter of showFullLeft & showSquareOnly, so it should show only squares which have a a fullest > 0

I'm getting 7 results back, but one of them is unwanted. It is square, but it has 0 for both full & partial

When I look at the query core data is using it looks correct

> CoreData: sql: SELECT t0.ZMANU, COUNT (DISTINCT  t0.Z_PK) FROM ZCOLOUR t0 JOIN ZPROJECTCOLOUR t1 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.ZCOLOUR JOIN ZPROJECTCOLOUR t2 ON t0.Z_PK = t2.ZCOLOUR JOIN ZPROJECT t3 ON t2.ZPROJECT = t3.Z_PK WHERE ( t1.ZFULLLEFT > ? AND  t3.ZDRILLTYPE = ?) GROUP BY  t0.ZMANU ORDER BY t0.ZMANU

> CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = 0

> CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = "Square"

When I print out the predicates I get

> (projectColours.fullLeft > 0) AND (projectColours.project.drillType == "Square")

Comment: Unrelated but prefer `!myArray.isEmpty` over `myArray.count > 0`.

Comment: Could you print `predicates` also? As it's more "iOS/macOS" oriented and maybe more readable (as CoreData adds plenty of prefixes to the classes)?

Comment: Do you want to get all object where ((any projectColour is showFullLeft) and (any projectColour is showSquareOnly)) or all object where (any projectColour is (showFullLeft and showSquareOnly))?

Comment: The original predicate which works was. SUBQUERY(projectColours, $pc, ($pc.fullLeft > 0) AND $pc.project.drillType ==[c] 'Square').@count > 0. 

I’m trying to avoid writing out individual predicates for each different combination of filters which was what I was doing originally

Comment: Please print the final `NSPredicate`, and add it in your question with the `Subquery` you're trying to match.

Comment: It looks like you need a subquery. Are all filters on projectColours?

Comment: It will all be on project colours.

Comment: I've added the print of the final predicate

Comment: For an explanation why you need a subquery see [Subquery Expression](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression/1411651-expressionforsubquery?language=objc). If you don't want to use a subquery then maybe you can fetch the project colours and extract or fetch the objects you want?